# Excel Formula to Remove/Replace parts of Column Texts and End of Text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this in a column:  `https://wrongSite.com/RandomTextToRemove/RandomAmountsOfTextCanBeHere/alwaysTheSameNameFolderForKeyingON/RandomText/RandomText/RandomText/RandomText/RandomText.html`

So remove anything in front of `alwaysTheSameNameFolderForKeyingON` and replace with `https://rightSite.com/`.  Then trim off the .html

I want this: `https://rightSite.com/alwaysTheSameNameFolderForKeyingON/RandomText/RandomText/RandomText/RandomText` (remove .html)

Something like this is as far as I got: So I have this now `SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(text, old_text1, "rightSite.com"), ".html",))`, but old_text1 is always changing - I need whatever is in front of /alwaysTheSameNameFolderForKeyingON to be old_text1. The other parts work

Comment: Have you considered using `SUBSTITUTE`?

Comment: @BigBen looking at it now.

Comment: @BigBen actually I lied I got most of it.  Issue being I need to Substitute unknown text values before a name to key on.  So I have this now SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(text, old_text1, https://rightSite.com), .html,)), but old_text1 is always changing - I need whatever is in front of /alwaysTheSameNameFolderForKeyingON to be old_text1.  The other parts work.